# On solution(s) to nonhomogeneous and corresponding homogeneous system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Actually there are two questions:

1. If one have a solution to nonhomogeneous system of linear equations $A x = b$, is it possible to say something about solution to corresponding homogeneous system $A x = 0$?
2. Is there a relation between solutions $x_1$ and $x_2$ to two nonhomogeneous systems $A x = b_1$ and $A x = b_2$

The matrix $A$ is square.

Comment: If you have *two* solutions of $Ax=b$, then their difference is a solution of $Ax=0$. One solution doesn't tell you much.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let $\bar{x}$ be a solution to $Ax=b$ and $v$ be a solution to
   $Ax=0$. From here, it follows

   $$A\bar{x} + Av = b$$

   $$A(\bar{x}+v) = b$$

   So, $\bar{x}+v$ is also a solution to $Ax=b$. In other words a
   solution to non-homogeneous system plus the solution to homogeneous
   system is also a solution to non-homogeneous system.
2. There is no relation between $x_1$ and $x_2$ since they are solutions to two different systems which happen to have the same $A$. In geometry point of view, think of $A$ as a transformation which transforms two arbitrary vectors $x_1$ and $x_2$ to two different vectors $b_1$ and $b_2$.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution of a nonhomogenous (linear) system equals to the sum of the general solution of a homogenous  system and a partial solution of a nonhomogenous  system. So e.g., if you find two solutions $x,x'$ of the first, you have a solution $x-x'$ of the last.